# Overriding a native class method in the Elementor Carousel Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm hoping someone can help here. My goal is to populate the slides in an element or carousel from an ACF repeater.

In short, I know I'd be laughing if I could override the `get_repeater_defaults()` method in the `Testimonial_Carousel` class. However, I've not figured out how to achieve it.

I couldn't find any suitable hooks, so I have had to clone the existing Elementor testimonial carousel widget and call it `acf-testiminonial-carousel`. That will allow me to customise the `get_repeater_defaults()` method in my own class.

However, although I can insert my widget using the widget panel, and controls-wise, it's an exact copy of the native carousel, it does not have the CSS or JS to style it or to make the slider work.

I've tried using `get_style_depends()` and `get_script_depends()` functions, but I don't know what the handles for the correct scripts are and if they'd work if I did.

So, can anyone see a way of

A) overriding the native `get_repeater_defaults()` method,

or

B) a way of loading the styles and JS into my cloned version?

Comment: Create a new class extending the Testimonial_Carousel and overwrite the method. Remember to call the parent if needed.

Comment: @MarkusZeller thanks. I considered that, but would I need to reregister the new extended class in place of the Testimonial_Carousel widget? I’m not over familiar with how Elementor widgets are loaded.

Comment: I think so. You need to use the new class "anyhow".